# MASM address with colon

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm working with x86 MASM assembler.
I've found wired call instruction, which has colon before the address:

```
  00459D2D: 9A 45 00 5F 9C 45  call        0045:9C5F0045
            00
```

Could somebody explain what is it? How it works?

Comment: That's a far pointer made up from segment and offset. If you don't know about segmentation this space is too short for explanation, go read some documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Call far instruction, it takes an absolute address that has a value both for the code segment and instruction pointer.

Ref: http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html

```
9A           = Call far instruction
45 00        = Value for code segment (0045)
5F 9C 45 00  = Value for instruction pointer (00459C5F)
```

Comment: X86 is little endian, so that 32 bit address should be 00459c5f (assuming the code byte dump is in byte order).

Comment: @rcgldr: Yes, that makes more sense.